# Hide class when refreshing site and scroll

Tags: html, jquery

I'm very new to this and I am trying to add a button to a header when scrolling 355 px.

This is my code:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
jQuery(function($){
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 355) {
        $('#categorymenu').removeClass('button-hidden');
    } else {
        $('.hfe-flyout-close').click();
        $('#categorymenu').addClass('button-hidden');
    }
});
});});
</script>
<style>
    #categorymenu.button-hidden{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

When I refresh the page, it gets reset. How can I make it not visible on refresh and make it visible as soon as I have scrolled 355 px?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to save information between site reloads, you could use cookies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your html code. I think you have missed to add class 'button-hidden' on initail render.

your code should be like follows when page render first time

```
<div id="categorymenu" class="button-hidden">
    <button value="save">save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This could be a solution, I am in no regards a web developer so adding stuff like this is hard for me but I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: This worked. I am "building" my website with a plugin and when I added the button-hidden class to the element within the plugin, it worked. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try `show()`and `hide()`. For example,

```js
    if (y > 355) {
        $('#categorymenu').show();
    } else {
        $('.hfe-flyout-close').click();
        $('#categorymenu').hide();
    }
```

Comment: It was build like this from the beginning and the same result, that is why I tried with adding and removing the class instead. It is like when the page is reloaded, the "y" gets reset, is there some way I can get around this?

I want it to be hidden on default, and show up on 355 px, that is all

Comment: When page is reloaded, did scroll changed??

Comment: Or you want to add the button and when page is reload the button should be in state `show` regardless the `scrollTop`??

Comment: When page is reloaded, scroll stays the same. If I scroll down past 355 px and scroll back up to the top, the button is hidden like it should be. If I refresh the page, it shows up even though I'm at the top of the page where it should be hidden. I can just scroll down a bit to hide it again but I want it hidden on default

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check scroll position on load you need to run your codes when dom is ready not only in scroll event. Here is an example:

```
function checkPos() {
var y = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (y > 355) {
        $('#categorymenu').removeClass('button-hidden');
    } else {
        $('.hfe-flyout-close').click();
        $('#categorymenu').addClass('button-hidden');
    }
}

$(document).on('ready scroll', checkPos());
```